# Get hash algorithm knowing hash, salt and password

Tags: hash

I have multiple salted hashes and I know the passwords, but I want to know the algorithm used to make the hash.

For example,

hash dcdc884c4ead4f713e9d15c1e14f5b07dfe184ea
salt 93295
password xx123123

Is there a way to know that? Thank you.

Comment: [Hashcat has a list](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) for password hashing. Check your output size, eliminate non-matching, then make sure that the rest uses salt, too. Now, on the remaining list, try each of them one by one.

Comment: The hash that you posted is 40 hexadecimal characters in length, so that's 20 bytes, or 160 bits - so it's likely SHA1.  As to how the salt is combined with the password, the number of iterations, etc. - that's a matter of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use designated tools for this purpose.

- You can just give the hash itself to program to list possibilities. [hashID by psypanda (installed in kali by default.)](https://github.com/psypanda/hashID)
- If you want to browse for more [hashcat has an example list of hashes.](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes)

Comment: I’ve tried everith